# Return Stripe Balance while avoiding loading times using JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am using Stripe API to return the balance/credit for a given customer on their dashboard, although the API takes a long time to run and the page loading time is suffering, annoying for just a single number. I specifically didn't want to save the balance to the database, so I looked at alternatives.

I have written the PHP API call to return the balance to a new file which I was calling using `setInterval` function and then updating the Div to display the balance, this works fine, although I do not want this function repeating at all, just looking for it to load and update once. I have added a preloader and ideally would like the preloader to display until such time as the balance has updated. Obviously I can't do this with `setInterval`. I have tried using some of the Javascript functions I know of such as window onload, but this doesn't update the balance at all?

I know this function isn't the option I need for this, although I know very little Javascript and any help or recommendations would be really appreciated. Here is what I currently have:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#balance").load('stripebalance.php);
    }, 10000);
</script>

<div id="preloader">
    <div id="loader"></div>
</div>

<div id="balance">
<h1>£-</h1>
</div>

<script>
$(window).on('load', function(){
  setTimeout(removeLoader, 2000);
});
function removeLoader(){
    $("#preloader").fadeOut(500, function() {
      $("#preloader").remove(); 
  });  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you'd just like to remove the pre-loader once you've loaded the data.

jQuery's [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) function supports a callback function to execute once the request completes

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#balance").load("stripebalance.php", function() {
    $("#preloader").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

There's no need for any intervals or timeouts in this.

---

Also, it's almost 2023 and you certainly don't need jQuery for this

```js
const getStripeBalance = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("stripebalance.php");
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Fetch error: ${res.status} - ${res.statusText}`);
  }
  return res.text();
}

const stripeBalanceHtmlPromise = getStripeBalance();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
  const balance = document.getElementById("balance");
  const loader = document.getElementById("preloader");
  const stripeBalanceHtml = await stripeBalanceHtmlPromise;
  balance.innerHTML = stripeBalanceHtml;

  loader.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
    loader.remove();
  });
  loader.classList.add("fadeOut");
});
```

```css
.fadeOut {
  animation: fadeOut 0.5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, does exactly what I needed it to. Thank you for the help, no more headache!